# Many UPDATE WHERE in one SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with very bad architecture and no one wants to fix anything and i have to work with what i have. So the problem is in the screen

[image: bd]

I need to update users connections and also some more fields... The solution which i see is `SET ... WHERE AND SET .. WHERE AND SET ... WHERE` (and yes, at this point i'm not even sure that it would work). So may be there is more common way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to provide solution.You can elaborate more on what you want to do

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a [`case statement`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your values are different records I think you will need to make individual updates.

You could also consider something like this:

```
UPDATE categories
    SET display_order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you should be updating all the fields in one single query. Why not try writing individual update queries and push it to database as a batch.